# No transport is located for protocol in akka 2.3.4 using Scala 2.11.1

Tags: scala, akka, actor, akka-remote-actor

I am getting this error when trying to run my akka application:

> [ERROR] [06/30/2014 15:58:14.591] [Thread-3] [RemoteActorRefProvider]
>   Error while looking up address [akka://FooPar0@127.0.0.1:2552]
>   akka.remote.RemoteTransportException: No transport is loaded for
>   protocol: [akka], available protocols: [akka.tcp]     at
>   akka.remote.Remoting$.localAddressFo
>   rRemote(Remoting.scala:88)
>   ...

My sbt project has the following build.sbt:

> name := "FooPar"
>
> version := "0.1"
>
> scalaVersion := "2.11.1"
>
> resolvers += "Typesafe Repository" at
>   "http://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/releases/"
>
> resolvers += "Sonatype Releases" at
>   "http://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/releases"
>
> libraryDependencies += "com.typesafe.akka" %% "akka-actor" % "2.3.4"
>
> libraryDependencies += "com.typesafe.akka" %% "akka-remote" % "2.3.4"
>
> libraryDependencies += "org.scalacheck" %% "scalacheck" % "1.11.4" %
>   "test"

Finally, the generated configuration string for my application looks like this:

> ```
> akka {
>   actor {
>     provider = "akka.remote.RemoteActorRefProvider"
>   }
>   remote { 
>         enabled-transports = ["akka.remote.netty.tcp"]
>
>         netty.tcp.hostname = "10.126.13.61" 
>         netty.tcp.port = 2552
>         netty.tcp.message-frame-size = 20 MiB
>         //netty.tcp {
>       //    write-buffer-high-water-mark = 148000b
>           //  send-buffer-size = 148000b
>            // receive-buffer-size = 148000b
>         //}
>   }
>
>   event-handlers = []
>   loglevel=WARNING
>
> }    
>
>
> my-custom-dispatcher {
> //    type = PinnedDispatcher
>     executor = thread-pool-executor
>     # 10 years should be enough
> //    thread-pool-executor.keep-alive-time = 315360000s
>     # note that disabling core timeout altogether doesn't work
>     # until ticket 2856 is fixed
>     thread-pool-executor.allow-core-timeout = off
>   mailbox-type = "akka.dispatch.UnboundedDequeBasedMailbox"
> }
> ```

Can someone help me locate the problem? I am following this guide here http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.3.4/scala/remoting.html, but it seems, my configuration file is just as it should be

As a response to Mario:

I am instantiating the ActorSystem from the config-string listed above and then via this code:

```
  private var system: Option[ActorSystem] = None
  def getSystem(machinefile: String) = synchronized {
    system match {
      case None =>
        system = Some(ActorSystem("FooPar" + indexOf(hostName, machinefile),
          ConfigFactory.parseString(conf))); system
      case Some(sys) => system
    }
  }
```

That is, I do not create `Address` objects explicitly.

Comment: What are you passing to `actorSelection` to find the remote actor?

Comment: This is an old codebase that I'm reviving, so still using deprecated way of 'sys.actorFor(name)'. Please have a bucket near you - you might get sick: http://pastebin.com/uzhPJLdY this is where the nightmare/magic happens.

Comment: Ouch... I've never tried remoting with `actorFor` but, as a test, try changing `akka://` to `akka.tcp://` in line 148. I'd seriously think of migrating to `actorSelection` ASAP since `actorFor` is now deprecated. Depending on what you're doing, it might just be a thing of changing `actorFor` to `actorSelection` and using an `Address` to select the actor.

Comment: This seems to alleviate the problem. Let me spend a few minutes to see if I can get it working correctly now :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This looks like a problem when creating the instance of `akka.actor.Address`. For remoting to work the first parameter has to be `"akka.tcp"` instead of `"akka"`:

```
val addr = Address("akka.tcp", "actorSystem", hostname, port)
```

Then when you want to get a reference to the actor:

```
val path = RootActorPath(addr) / "user" / "actorName"
val actorRef = context.actorSelection(path)
```

(note that `context` might also be `system`)

As stated in the comments, since you're using `actorFor`, try using `akka.tcp://` instead of `akka://` in the URL.

Comment: using akka.tcp:// instead solved my problem. Thanks a billion! And a wholly sarcastic thanks to the error message from Akka xD. Really happy now :D

Comment: For bonus points, if I want to migrate to use 'context.actorSelection(path)', how do I get hold of the ActorRef for that actor? Later in my program, I need to use an ActorRef instance in this code:

Await.result(localActor ? GroupReceive(fromRank), timeout.duration)

Comment: `ActorSelection` also suports the `ask` syntax. For most purposes you can use it as you would an `ActorRef` (except for the fact that it might point to nowhere if an actor doesn't exist, or to multiple actors if you used a wildcard). Have a look at http://letitcrash.com/post/55250716550/2-2-spotlight-actorselection-instead-of-actorfor. If you _really_ need an honest-to-god `ActorRef`, you can send an `Identify` message to the `ActorSelection`. Have a look at http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.2.0/project/migration-guide-2.1.x-2.2.x.html#Use_actorSelection_instead_of_actorFor.

Comment: ...another difference that might be pertinent, the `ActorSelection` is looked up for each message send, while `ActorRef` isn't. http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.3.4/scala/actors.html#actorselection-scala

Comment: The last point could prove to be vital. Also, I only see tell (!) no ask (!?) in here: http://doc.akka.io/api/akka/snapshot/?_ga=1.3798323.285168968.1404129424#akka.actor.ActorSelection

Comment: `ask` and `?` aren't defined in `Actor` either, that's why you have to `import akka.pattern.ask`, which does some implicit magic to get them to you

Comment: Another option for getting the `ActorRef` from an `ActorSelection` is in this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18012945/how-can-i-check-if-an-akka-actor-exists-akka-2-2/19834008#19834008