# Create an actor if it does not exists in scala akka cannot find the actor

Tags: scala, akka, actor

Based on [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19834008/1545579) I have implemented the following, but it throws an exception saying that the actor with that name already exists:

```
    implicit val timeout = Timeout(5 seconds)
    val pathToLookup: String = self.path.toString + "/" + actorName

    context.actorSelection(pathToLookup).resolveOne().onComplete(useActor)
    def useActor(possible: Try[ActorRef]) = {
      val definite = possible match {
        case Success(actor) =>
          log.debug("Found an actor " + actorName)
          actor
        case Failure(_) =>
          log.debug("Creating a new actor " + actorName)
          context.actorOf(Props[MyActor], name = actorName)
      }
      // other code
    }
```

I have a feeling that I am not passing  the right path to `actorSelection` but I do not see how to fix it.

Edit: I corrected the path of the child actor, and it still does not find the actor. I also tried `toStringWithoutAddress` but it does not work either.

Comment: Have you also considered using `context.child(name)`? You can check if a child for that given name exists and create an actor if it doesn't.

Comment: Thanks @mavilein It solved my problem at hand! (even though I couldn't get `actorSelection` to work)

Answer (score 1):

`ActorySystem.actorOf(props)` creates top level actors, that will be directly under `/user/` while `context.actorOf(props)` inside of an actor creates actors as children of that actor so they will have the path `/user/path/to/parent/child`.

The problem is that you are looking for the actors under `/user/[name]` but you are creating them as children of your current actor, so they will be at something like `/user/myactor/[name]`.

Also note, that you are closing over actor state and using internal actor things from a different thread which is unsafe when you are using `onComplete` and `context` like that. See the warning in this section about that: http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.4.1/scala/actors.html#Ask__Send-And-Receive-Future

Comment: Thanks for the correction, but it still does not work for me. Also thanks for the warning. In my code, now I am using `context.child` as suggested by mavilein.