# creating Akka actor hierarchies lazily

Tags: scala, file-io, akka

I want to create actors that can serve resources from the file system. Ideally [1] I'd like to have one actor for each directory and each file. But I don't want to create the whole actor tree hierarchy as I would like to save memory and resources as much as possible.

As I understand an actor can only be created if its parent exists. What is the best best way to create these hierarchies lazily. Is there a hook one can use to capture failures and create the actor hierarchies on the fly, and do so efficiently?

Having this would allow me to send `fetch`, `update`, `delete`, ... messages to an actor and the akka actor system would thereby deal with synchronisation issues. This could then be extended to more sophisticated actor behaviours later with notions of virtual files or such...

Some possible solutions I can think of:

1. run `context.actorFor(path)` and if it returns the dead letter mailbox, try to create the actor hierarchies. This does not sound like a good solution.
2. send the message to the root actor and have it forward it to its child with some `getOrCreateChild` method. But would this perhaps be inefficient? ( or is this just what akka itself does under the hood... ( I should look ))
3. not do this at all and just create one actor that delegates every message to a directory actor created on the fly for each directory of the requested file as explained in the answers to the Stack overflow question ["on demand actor get or else create"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10766187/on-demand-actor-get-or-else-create). This would not be very good for capturing directory deletion semantics. ( Would it be a lot more efficient?)

[1] I am not absolutely sure if this is ideal, but I thought I should try this method out first. Another method is just to create an actor for each directory and store that in a hash map.

Comment: I just disvovered akka Agents. I wonder if for something like mapping the file system (for the purpose of a web server), Agents would not be better, as I expect reads on this data structure to be much more common. There is little documentation on those, and I am not sure where those are going. It is not stated how much memory Agents take, and it does not seem easy to change the behavior of Agents. One's application would also then need to manage the map from URIs->Agents

Answer (score 2):

First, actors are very lightweight.  You can have millions running in a JVM with an extremely small footprint for the actors itself.  Obviously this changes if the actors have some custom state that can be big memory wise, but the actors themselves have a very small footprint.

Now if you still want to implement them lazily, one approach might be to have a single File or Folder master actor that receives all of the initial calls.  This actor checks the system to see if an actor exists already to serve the request for whatever folder or file the request is for.  If not, the master creates it and then forwards the message to it.  If so, it just forwards the message to it.  No need to keep a hashmap in memory as the `ActorSystem` itself will hold all of the `ActorRefs` for you and give you a means to look them up.  You just need a method of equating file name/path to the actor name.  An oversimplified example of the master could look like this:

```
case class Fetch(path:String)
class FileMaster extends Actor{
  def receive = {
    case msg @ Fetch(path) =>
      val ref = lazyFindActor[FileHandler](path)
      ref.forward(msg)
  }

  def lazyFindActor[T <: Actor: Manifest](name:String) = {
    val ref = context.actorFor(name)
    if (ref == context.system.deadLetters){
      context.actorOf(Props[T], name)
    }
    else{
      ref
    }
  } 
}
```

All `lazyFindActor` does is check if the actor for the path already has been created and started.  If so, it forwards to it. If not (and it compares to `deadLetters` to make this determination as unfortunately, I don't see a better way to check if an actor exists), it creates one under the supervision of the master and then forwards to it.  The next time the same path comes in it will then use the pre-existing `Actor`.

You may have to do a little work translating from a file path syntax into something that can be used for an actor name (because akka uses a hierarchical file path like structure for actor paths already), but I'm not 100% sure about that one.  Just wanted to throw a high level concept at you and see if this is what you were looking for.

Comment: thanks for the code :-) It looks like you are combining the possible solution outline 1. and 3. I added in the description of the problem. You don't use a hashmap as I thought of doing in 3, but you used the naming hierarchy, where names can contain slashes in them. --- The advantage I can see of having the file paths and the akka paths correspond would be that a call to the file path could directly call the right actor so that directories could contain their file actors. If one goes the way you suggest then one needs to always pass through the root actor for directory creation.

Comment: I don't necessarily see going through the master as an issue. It's a pretty common pattern in actor systems to route messages through multiple actors, each serving a distinct purpose in the overall flow of servicing that message.  Here, the masters responsibility is to always ensure that the appropriate actor instance is handing the message.  Also, you could rewrite the master as a custom Akka `Router` instead if you were worried about incurring two mailbox hits for the servicing of one message.  Routers skip the mailbox entirely.

Comment: Thanks for the tip on `Router`s. I'll look into that.

Comment: The above solution requires as you say encoding path names in order to remove the '/' as otherwise it clashes with the akka path namespaces.

Comment: I figured as much.  I suppose you could try replacing `/` with something like `-`...