# Get or create child Akka actor and ensure liveness

Tags: scala, akka, actor, race-condition

I am trying to use a hierarchy of Akka actors to handle per user state. There is a parent actor that owns all the children, and handles the get-or-create in the correct way (see [a1](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16281139/8261), [a2](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10772234/8261)):

```
class UserActorRegistry extends Actor {
  override def Receive = {
    case msg@ DoPerUserWork(userId, _) =>
      val perUserActor = getOrCreateUserActor(userId)
      // perUserActor is live now, but will it receive "msg"?
      perUserActor.forward(msg)
  }

  def getOrCreateUserActor(userId: UserId): ActorRef = {
    val childName = userId.toActorName
    context.child(childName) match {
      case Some(child) => child
      case None => context.actorOf(Props(classOf[UserActor], userId), childName)
  }
}
```

In order to reclaim memory, the `UserActors` expire after a period of idleness (i.e. a timer triggers the child actor to call `context.stop(self)`).

My problem is that I think I have a race condition between the "getOrCreateUserActor" and the child actor receiving the forwarded message -- if the child expires in that window then the forwarded message will be lost.

Is there any way I can either detect this edge case, or refactor the `UserActorRegistry` to preclude it?

Comment: It become simpler if you maintain the list of child actors explicitly in a map.  Then, you can have child actors signal timeouts by sending an expiry message to the parent, which causes the parent to stop the child and clean up the map.  The map is maintained synchronously (from the parent actor's perspective), so the race condition goes away.

Comment: That sounds sensible. I'll also have to use the map to look up child actors, rather than looking them up by name, otherwise there might be conflicts where the child is scheduled to die, but still exists in Akka's map of children. It feels wasteful to maintain a separate child Map when Akka has this map already.

Comment: A separate map does seem redundant.. More so considering I often maintain two maps, the second indexing by ActorRef, to efficiency clean up the first when I receive a Terminated. Yes, interesting, would be slick to use child().

Comment: "would be slick to use child()" -- yes, that's what I was trying to do, but it led to the race condition in this question :-(

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I can see two problems with your current design that open yourself up to the race condition you mention:

1) Having the termination condition (timer sending a poison pill) go directly to the child actor.  By taking this approach, the child can certainly be terminated on a separate thread (within the dispatcher) while at the same time, a message has been setup to be forwarded to it in the `UserActorRegistry` actor (on a different thread within the dispatcher).

2) Using a `PoisonPill` to terminate the child.  A `PoisonPill` is for a graceful stop, allowing for other messages in the mailbox to be processed first.  In your case, you are terminating due to inactivity, which seems to indicate no other messages already in the mailbox.  I see a `PoisonPill` as wrong here because in your case, another message might be sent after the `PosionPill` and that message would surely be lost after the `PoisonPill` is processed.

So I'm going to suggest that you delegate the termination of the inactive children to the `UserActorRegistry` as opposed to doing it in the children themselves.  When you detect the condition of inactivity, send a message to the instance of `UserActorRegistry` indicating that a particular child needs to be terminated.  When you receive that message, terminate that child via `stop` instead of sending a `PoisonPill`.  By using the single mailbox of the `UserActorRegistry` which is processed in a serial manner, you can help ensure that a child is not about to be terminated in parallel while you are about to send it a message.

Now, there is a complication here that you have to deal with.  Stopping an actor is asynchronous.  So if you call `stop` on a child, it might not be completely stopped when you are processing a `DoPerUserWork` message and thus might send it a message that will be lost because it's in the process of stopping.  You can solve this by keeping some internal state (a List) that represents children that are in the process of being stopped.  When you stop a child, add its name to that list and then setup `DeathWatch` (via `context watch child`) on it.  When you receive the `Terminated` event for that child, remove it's name from the list of children being terminated.  If you receive work for a child while its name is in that list, requeue it for re-processing, maybe up to a max number of times so as to not try and reprocess forever.

This is not a perfect solution; it's just an identification of some of the issues with your approach and a push in the right direction for solving some of them.  Let me know if you want to see the code for this and I'll whip something together.

**Edit**

In response to your second comment.  I don't think you'll be able to look at a child `ActorRef` and see that it's currently shutting down, thus the need for that list of children that are in the process of being shutdown.  You could enhance the `DoPerUserWork` message to contain a numberOfAttempts:Int field and increment this and send back to self for reprocessing if you see the target child is currently shutting down.  You could then use the numberOfAttempts to prevent re-queuing forever, stopping at some max number of attempts.  If you don't feel completely comfortable relying on `DeathWatch`, you could add a time-to-live component to the items in the list of children shutting down.  You could then prune items as you encounter them if they are in the list but have been in there too long.

Comment: Thanks; very helpful. I'm not actually using `PoisonPill`, but the child actor is calling `context.stop(self)` after a timeout: I have updated the question. Sorry for the confusion. The rest of your explanation still makes a lot of sense.

Comment: "Stopping an actor is asynchronous" -- this is the key issue here, I think. After I have called `context.stop(child)` from the parent, but the child still appears via `context.child(name)` what state will it be in? Indeterminate state? What can I do with incoming `DoPerUserWork` messages during that period? I suppose I'll have to queue them. I won't be allowed to create a new child with the same name during this indeterminate period, will I? And a list of "children being terminated" is the only way to detect this zombie state? Will that list need a timeout as well, or can I rely on DeathWatch?

Comment: @Rich, I added more to the answer to address your second question.