# How to synchronize killing of child Actor using setReceiveTimeout in Akka

Tags: multithreading, akka

Background:
I am using C#, but I think this question applies to Java and Scala as well.  I have one master actor that passes along all "Job Messages".  These jobs can be executed at the same time, as long as they don't share don't share a "concurrency id".  To take care of this, I was spawning one child actor for each "concurrency id".  I then used setReceiveTimeout to clean up the children when they've been idle.

What I can't figure out is how I can do this without a race condition.  Here are a couple of ways that don't work:
1) Remove the child from the Dictionary, and tell the child to terminate.  This does not work because messages might have been added to the child's queue between the time the timeout was fired, and before the parent started processing the message, resulting in messages being lost.
2) Remove the child from the Dictionary, and send a PoisonPill.  This does not work because the child might continue to process new work.  If more work reaches the parent, the parent would create a new child, and the means two thing with the same concurrency id are running at the same time.
3) Remove the child from the dictionary, and "ask" the child with a message.  If the message returns

Is there any way the parent can ask the child if there are any messages in the child's queue?  (This would not be a race condition, because all messages to the child come from the parent)

Can the parent check if the child's queue is empty, and the child isn't processing anything?

Should I add a new message and "ask" the child if it's done?  (This would be safe because I know the parent is the only one who sends messages, but there's a moderate chance this might block if the child is processing a message, or if the there's no threads available in the dispatcher's pool.

My question is similar to this question, but I'm adding the additional constraint of the "concurrency id", and not worried about "zombie actors" who are currently shutting down, as long as the zombies have no work and won't get more work:
[Get or create child Akka actor and ensure liveness](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23629159/get-or-create-child-akka-actor-and-ensure-liveness)

Comment: This reads as a horrible story.

Comment: @ErnodeWeerd It sounds like you want me to improve my question, but I'm not sure what you want me to improve.  Can you be more explicit?

Comment: Killing, children, parent, terminate, zombie, pool, poison, pill, liveness. Need I say more? It might be a perfectly fine question, I don't know but it gives me the shivers.

Comment: @ErnodeWeerd You're right.  On a second reading, it does sounds a bit like a bad horror movie.

Comment: May I suggest changing the title and text to always use “child Actor” or simply “Actor” where applicable (instead of the ambiguous “child”)? Also “terminate” is the correct technical term instead of “kill”.

Comment: @RolandKuhn Thanks for the suggestion about the title.  I'm using the term "kill" since that is the term Akka uses.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Akka makes sure that actor mailboxes are private. The mailbox of one actor is no business of another actor. A parent checking if the child's mailbox is empty would be wrong.

Why do you think ask would block?

One option: do not kill the children. If you have a fixed set of concurrency IDs you use over and over again and again, just keep all the actors alive. Actors do not consume too much resources.

Another option:

```
When the parent wants to kill the child:
send a PoisonPill to the child and remove him from the Dictionary.

When the parent receives a "job message" with concurrencyID:
if (Dictionary.contains(concurrencyID) {
    send message to child
} else {
    if (parent has child with name concurrencyID) {
        delay message - for example with scheduler // child is terminating
    } else {
        create a child with name concurrencyID
        send message to child
    }
}
```

Comment: I meant that I could do an ask, and block, waiting for the child to respond, so I know the child was done.

Comment: @PatrickM Well... Don't do that then! (Blocking in Akka never good.)

Comment: Agreed.  I have that as an example of a solution I thought had problems.

Comment: Sadly, I do not have a fixed set of concurrency ids.  The ids change over time, since they correspond objects I'm working on.  The code that you wrote is basically what I have.  My problem is that the child might keep running jobs with that id while it has a PoisonPill in the queue.  That means a new child might be created with the same name and be running while the old one is still running.

Comment: @PatrickM No it won't. The `if (parent has child with name concurrencyID)` part ensures that that the job is delayed when the child is still alive.

Comment: This isn't exactly what I wanted, but it put me on the right track.  I ended up using code that's like this, except I also track the last time I sent a message to a child to know which are safe to remove.